# sql query with patients

Tags: sql

Need help with a database query;

```
patients(cpr(key), firstname, sirname, address, postalnumber, country, journal)
allergies(allergens(key)), allergytype, allergic_reaction)
patientallergies(allergens(key), cpr(key))
```

How do we write CPR-numbers pairwise on patients who are allergic against the exact same allergens? A CPR number can only be printed once and a CPR number cannot be paired with itself.

Our current suggestion goes something like this:

```
SELECT p1.cpr, p2.cpr
FROM patients p1, patients p2
```

Not sure where to go from here

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Help use help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 0):

One method is a self-join and aggregation.  This uses window functions to count the number of allergens per patient to be sure the match is exact:

```
with pa as (
      select pa.*, count(*) over (partition by cpr) as cnt
      from patientallergies pa
     )
select pa.cpr, pa2.cpr
from pa join
     pa pa2
     on pa.allergan = pa2.allergan and pa.cnt = pa2.cnt
group by pa.cpr, pa2.cpr, pa.cnt
having count(*) = pa.cnt;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, would this return the pairs that have the same allergies? And not those who have the same amount of allergies

Comment: @jubibanna . . . They have to have the same allergies.  That is what `pa.allergan = pa2.allergan` imposes.